# Sending user back to LoginPage not working in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin Forms with Shell app, I decided to add a `LoadingPage` page to keep user occupied as I make a few API calls after the user logs in or signs up for the first time. I register my `LoginPage` and `LoadingPage` in my `AppShell` in this order -- see below:

```
<TabBar>
   <ShellContent Route="LoginPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate login:LoginPage}" />
</TabBar>

<TabBar>
   <ShellContent Route="LoadingPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate login:LoadingPage}" />
</TabBar>
```

Once the user logs in and I get authentication response, I send the user to `LoadingPage` like this:

```
var route = $"{nameof(LoadingPage)}?UserName={result.UserName}&Email={result.Email}";
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(route);
```

This part works fine. The trouble is when I log user off. As the last step of my log off process, I use the following code to send user to `LoginPage`:

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"///{nameof(LoginPage)}");
```

Instead of going to `LoginPage`, I end up on `LoadingPage`. I tried this several times and every time, I ended up on `LoadingPage`.

Another important point is that I implemented the following on both the `LoginPage` and `LoadingPage` in order to prevent user trying to go back to them:

```
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
{
   return true;
}
```

This may be causing the issue but haven't been able to figure it out exactly. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen anyone put TWO `TabBar`s in a Shell.

I think change those `<TabBar>`s to `<Tab>`s.

(When a Shell sees a series of `<Tab>`s, it implicitly creates ONE `TabBar` to hold them.)

---

One technique for these special pages that are not part of the main functionality of app, is to not start shell until user is through the startup process (loaded and logged in).

These pages would NOT be declared in Shell xaml, nor given routes.

To use, set App’s MainPage directly:

```cs
// In App.xaml.cs.
MainPage = new LoadingPage();
…
// After loaded, or after logout.
Application.Current.MainPage = new LoginPage();
…
// After successful login.
Application.Current.MainPage = new AppShell();
```

---

[Absolute Routes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation#absolute-routes). Use TWO forward slashes (you show THREE).

```cs
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(LoginPage)}");
```

The use of THREE slashes is specialized: its one type of [Relative Route](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation#relative-routes); it searches in hierarchy "below" (child or descendent of) the current page. E.g. its one way to get to one of two pages named "detail", that are in different parts of hierarchy.

I'm not sure exactly what happened - depends on what page was showing when logged out, and what was on nav stack - but the symptom suggests that routing got confused; did not make it to LoginPage. Because it wasn't a child (or descendent) of currently showing page.

Comment: I changed it to `<Tab>` but for some reason I can no longer pass my query parameters to my `LoadingPage` if I use an absolute route. If I register the route for `LoadingPage` as a detail page in `AppShell.xaml.cs`, I'm able to pass my query params but the original problem still persists. I added `OnAppearing()` method to `LoginPage` just to see if I'll hit it after I log off. Looks like for some reason, after logging off, I go straight to `LoadingPage` instead of `LoginPage` so I never hit the `OnAppearing()` method. Strange, isn't it?

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: I really appreciate your help with this. Here's what's bugging me though. Why would it go to `LoadingPage` even though I tell it to go to the `LoginPage`? To me, that's really the main issue here. I can certainly go with your suggestion of not even introducing the `Shell` until the authentication process is completed but that still doesn't tell me what's going on here. Another reason why I'm reluctant to take that route is that the issue surfaces once I log off which means by that time, `AppShell` will be introduced.

Comment: I understand. Re re-introducing AppShell, I considered that, but decided it was good to create a new one after a new Login. (If want to re-use, then store it in a static variable of App.) To help ensure a clean state; nothing left from previous user's actions. When I get time, I'll see if I can reproduce the issue with what page it goes to. Did you look in Output pane for messages? Feels like something goes wrong with route, and some default is occurring. Perhaps LoadingPage was on the nav stack, and got revealed when something went wrong with Routing.